# UIButton addTarget: Call a method from another class

Tags: objective-c, class, methods, uibutton

Idea below the code is to have an interaction between two classes. When pressing the button, I want to print a statement in another class.
When I press the button I could not print "Test".

**Buttonclass.m:**

```
 HjulGenkendelse *hjulRecognizer = [[HjulGenkendelse alloc] init];
    [knap addTarget:hjulRecognizer action:@selector(hjul:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

**HjulGenkendelse.h**

```
 @interface HjulGenkendelse : UIGestureRecognizer
 - (void)hjul:(UIButton *) sender;
```

**HjulGenkendelse.m**

```
- (void)hjul:(UIButton *) sender
{
  NSLog(@"Test!");
}
```

Does someone have any solution to my problem ?

Thanks by advance :)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is likely to be here:

```
HjulGenkendelse *hjulRecognizer;
[knap addTarget:hjulRecognizer action:@selector(hjul:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

In the first line you are declaring an object. But you aren't actually creating the object. So, if you are using ARC, this is helpfully initialised to `nil`. You are then adding `nil` as the target for the action. Because it doesn't have a target, the action is not getting sent. (This is not strictly true, but you should look up Nil-targetted actions and the Responder Chain to know why).

The fix is to simple instantiate an object to be the target of the action. Change the first line to

```
HjulGenkendelse *hjulRecognizer = [[HjulGenkendelse alloc] init];
```

Use whatever initialiser is appropriate if init is not suitable for the HjulGenkendelse class.